# Python property

Tags: python, properties

The output seems a bit fishy given the following code. Why is "get in Base" only printed once? And why is not "set in Base" printed at all? The actual getting/setting seems to work fine though. What am I missing?

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        self.s = "BaseStr"

    def getstr(self):
        print "get in Base"
        return self.s
    def setstr(self, s):
        print "set in Base"
        self.s = s
    str = property(getstr, setstr)

b = Base()
print b.str
b.str = "Foo"
print b.str
```

Output:

```
get in Base
BaseStr
Foo
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to use [new-style classes](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes) for properties to work correctly. To do so derive your class from `object`:

```
class Base(object):
    ...
```

Comment: And, for Python 3.x, you don't need to do this. All classes in Python3 are new style.

Comment: But if I don't subclass `object`, I can still create `property` in the classic class, why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever creating a new class, derive it from the `object` type.